# Possessive pronoun vs definite article in this sentence

Tags: definite-article, possessive-pronouns

In some languages, such as French and Spanish, it's ungrammatical or at least uncommon to use possessive pronouns to refer to parts of the body in some contexts: People say "the head," "the face" to refer to their own face, at least in some circumstances or kinds of constructions. But when the noun as an object is not a body part, possessive pronouns are ungrammatical or strange, at least in many cases.

It seems that English might have different grammar in this respect. I don't know what rules dictate the use of a definite article OR a possessive pronoun in my sentence but my intuition is B is more correct. I don't know why. Can anyone tell me whether A is also acceptable and if not, why only B is right?

A. In ***his*** dissertation on biodiversity submitted yesterday, John explored ... (extraneous information omitted)
B. In ***the*** dissertation on biodiversity submitted yesterday, ...

Comment: Did you research this topic? If so, what did you find? There are already discussions about this issue on SE, e.g. here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295279/is-there-any-rule-about-when-to-choose-a-definite-article-or-a-possessive-pronou

Comment: Yes I've seen this one but mine is about their uses when there is something (a modifier) that explicitly indicates the object, not a body part

Comment: Both sentences are correct. In the first, the dissertation belongs to John. In the second, it doesn't necessarily. (Perhaps it had several other authors and John only contributed a couple of paragraphs.)

Answer (score 1):

English is probably different from your native/other language(s) in this way:

It's common to use the word "possession" in grammar to mean a more general kind of relationship indicated by a "possessive pronoun".

For example, I don't own "my sister". (I did previously, but I sold her because she is somewhat impolite.)

Both of the sentences in your example are grammatical and natural.

We use the definite article, *the,* to introduce nouns (noun phrases) when we know or believe that the hearer shares information with us. In other words, if I ask, "Did you like the movie?" I assume or know that you will understand which movie I am talking about.

In your example, we would usually only use the definite article if we had just previously mentioned that dissertation, and/or if it was not important in our mind whose it was when we speak:

> John worked very hard on *his* dissertation and submitted it yesterday. He told me that he was fairly proud of *the* dissertation and had high hopes that it would be accepted.

For body parts, it's more common in English to use possessive pronouns, and would sometimes sound a bit odd or be ungrammatical to use an article if we know whose body part we are referring to.

> I hurt the hand

Ungrammatical if I mean that I hurt my hand.

> The dog licked her face.

> The dog licked her in the face.

Both of these are grammatical and natural.

I cannot give a very complete answer, at least right now. But I suggest that you might search for information specifically about possessive pronouns and body parts, since this is a common issue for English learners from some (or perhaps most) backgrounds.